# Camera app for easy selfie taking (either timer and/or big button)?

Tags: gratis, android, camera

I have an android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean phone.  I find taking selfies problematic because there is no dedicated camera button on my phone with the stock camera app.  Is there a free app that has any (or all) of the following features?

- Self timer
- Very large on screen shutter button (so I can press without looking at it)
- Can use volume button as shutter button

If it's free and has ads that's okay but I prefer apps with the most minimal permissions necessary to do the job.

I found this app which is okay:

[`Self Timer camera & 4 shoot F by BEZ.SYSTEM`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.system_boo.self_timer_free&hl=en)

But an annoyance with this app is that it seems to have beep when it takes the picture which you can turn off but it doesn't seem to remember the setting between application runs.

Maybe there is something better?

Comment: Would voice activated camera apps work, or will you be using it in public/noisy environments? Also, if you're willing to buy an accessory, there are bluetooth remote shutters for selfies and group photos, which are better in my opinion. [Here is an example](http://www.amazon.com/Hapurs-Bluetooth-Wireless-Control-Shutter/dp/B00N8J7SIM).

Comment: @Timmy: would be using in noisy environments so voice activated probably would not work.  Wasn't aware of remote shutters, pretty interesting actually although I'd still prefer an app

Comment: Yupp. There are even a lot of [camera remote controls](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_tools#group_225) available for Android. And [here's an example selfie remote at Amazon](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B00O0XA3L4/) – just about EUR 5 :)